# can we manually drag custom time bar? or is there any way to trigger timechanged event after setCustomTime method?

Tags: vis.js

can we manually drag custom time bar? or is there any way to trigger timechanged event after setCustomTime method?

if I need to request a feature please do advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you can see on [this example](http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/other/customTimeBars.html), the custom-time bar can be moved manually.
And after the setCustomTime method, you can get the time as you can see on the same example.

Comment: I'm sorry if I couldn't make my point clear enough, I think I should change the question accordingly afterwards

what I meant was, I need to trigger the timechanged event even if I use setCustomeTime, since the only time the timechanged event triggers is when you drag the custom time bar by dragging, and by "manually dragging timebar" I meant by code, since I needed to somehow trigger the timechanged event...
can i trigger the timechanged event myself? if I can how, just triggering the event as I need to

thanks for your time